# Loading Models in XNA without the Content Pipeline

Tags: c#, xna

Now, I love XNA.  It's an awesome framework, except for one thing.

The content pipeline.

It's a huge no-no for any game that encourages modding and user-created content, especially for a game like mine which practically depends on it.

How would one go about loading a skinned+animated .x file into a Model class?

I assume that you have to load the file normally, parse it, and build up a Model out of ModelMeshes, but I don't have any clue how I would go about creating ModelMeshes from scratch.

I don't even need you to tell me how to do it, pointing to some good articles or tutorials would be perfect.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I have searched around for this, a lot, but everything I see just tells me to use the content pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for loading .x files only, I don't have any answers except to refer you to the [.X file format reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But since you mention that user-created content is very important - I will point out that [COLLADA](http://collada.org) is a great option. [Open Model Implementation for XNA](http://omixna.codeplex.com/) is a good library that can get you started loading COLLADA files, but it is still upto you to render them - or use the OMI renderer.

Hope this helps some!

Comment: COLLADA looks cool, but I'd prefer to use the built-in renderer.  Thanks for the reference, too, and I think you forgot a link :P

Comment: "Alternatively, you could check out" and then you don't say anything else.

Comment: :) Thanks, I totally missed that bit. I can't quite remember what I meant to say then, so I've taken it off.

Comment: Actually, I think I will go with my own file format since .NET has a great XML implementation.  Thank you for enlightening me about COLLADA, though, it inspired me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the models at runtime if you so desire. This will lead to long loading times of you have a lot of files so I suggest saving the results from the compilation and only recompiling if necessary (new file or changes since last compilation).

There is a sample that does thin somewhere on the AppHub but I suggest you check out [this project](http://xnacontentcompiler.codeplex.com/) it should be very easy to modify to do exactly what you need.

Also check out the [gamedev stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) if you have more gamedev related questions.

Edit: Also huge thumbs up on supporting the modding community that inevitably pops up around any good game which I'm sure your will be.

Comment: Personally, I'd only compile stuff to .xnb if I really have to, as like a last resort.  I'd prefer to just read the .x file directly into a Model, which I understand will take work on my part.